# How to get public property in ImageURL?

Tags: c#, image, imageurl

I have one public property named "ID"

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

and an asp Image control

```
<asp:Image ID="ImagePicture"  runat="server" />
```

I want to get the ID into a ImageURL. I tried like this

```
<asp:Image ID="ImagePicture"  ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?ID='<%= ID %> runat="server" />
```

but I get an Error: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Does anyone know how I can fix it, or propose me another way to get the ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot cleaner to just do this in the code behind:

```
ImagePicture.ImageUrl = string.Format("ImageHandler.ashx?ID={0}", this.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the value by the page_load method?

Something like that should work:

```
ImagePicture.imageURL = "yourLink.ashx?id=" + valueParam;
```